# R - Using rvest to scrape a password protected website without logging in at each loop iteration

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape data from a password protected website in R using the rvest package. My code currently logs in to the website at each iteration of a loop that will run about 15,000 times. This seems very inefficient but I have not figured out a way around it, because jumping to a different url without first logging in every time returns to the website's log in page. A simplification of my code is as follows:

```
library(rvest)
url <- password protected website url within quotes
session <-html_session(url)
form <-html_form(session)[[1]]

filled_form <- set_values(form,
                      `username` = email within quotes, 
                      `password` = password within quotes)
start_table <- submit_form(session, filled_form) %>%
  jump_to(url from which to scrape first table within quotes) %>%
  html_node("table.inlayTable") %>%
  html_table()
data_table <- start_table

for(i in 1:nrow(data_ids))
{
current_table <- try(submit_form(session, filled_form) %>%
  jump_to(paste(first part of url within quotes, data_ids[i, ], last part of url within quotes, sep="")) %>%
  html_node("table.inlayTable") %>%
  html_table())

data_table <- rbind(data_table, current_table)
}
```

For simplicity, the way I handle any possible errors thrown within the try function is suppressed. Note that data_ids is a data frame containing the part of the url to be updated at each new iteration.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how this scraping could be achieved without logging in at each iteration of the loop?

Thank you! Yann

Answer (score 1):

You can save the session in a variable but you won't save so many time I guess.
Here is my script for web scraping :

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://"
session <- html_session(url)              
form <- html_form(session)[[1]]

filled_form <- set_values(form,`[login]` = "xxx",`[password]` = "xxx")

session <- submit_form(session,filled_form)

for (i in unique(id)) {
      link <- paste0("https://",i,"xxx")
      df_all <- session %>% jump_to(link) %>% html_table()
        if ( length(df_all) != 0 ) {
          my_df <- as.data.frame(df_all[n],optional = TRUE)
          database <- rbind(my_df,database)
          cat("Data saved for",i)
          } else {
          cat("No data for",i)
          }
         }
```

Comment: Did this answer work? Is there a better answer you found ?