# Scraping in page with a login

Tags: r, rvest

I made sure to look at other rvest question on stackexchange before asking. In particular:

[R - Using rvest to scrape a password protected website without logging in at each loop iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108711/r-using-rvest-to-scrape-a-password-protected-website-without-logging-in-at-eac)

and

[Using rvest to scrape a website w/ a login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43700708/using-rvest-to-scrape-a-website-w-a-login-page)

I am trying to scrape the ex-dividend dates using rvest from dividend.com

Following the above code, I wrote code but I seem to have trouble.

```
# ADDRESS OF LOGIN PAGE:
URL <- "https://www.dividend.com/login/"

# CREATE PAGE SESSION
pgsession <- html_session(URL)

# CREATE PAGE FORM
pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[2]]  # Problem is here,  I get a blank list

# FILL IN PASSWORD AND ID
filled_form <-  set_values(form,
                  user_login = email within quotes, 
                  password = password within quotes)

# GO TO EX-DIVIDEND DATE PAGE AND SCRAPE
div_data <-  submit_form(pgsession, filled_form) %>% 
jump_to(url from which `to scrape first table within quotes)`
 %>% html_node(list("td a", "td span", "tr td") %>% html_table()
```

But html_form(pgsession) returns me a blank list().

Can anyone provide me some help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if everything else works as intended I think the issues is with using a `html_session` object inside `html_form`. It is expecting a node or a node set so I think this should work.

```
# CREATE PAGE FORM
pgform <- html_form(read_html("https://www.dividend.com/login/"))
```

You still have to subset the correct form from the `pgform` object but I think this should be it.